# Merge multiple csv files in python

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, merge

Need help with merging multiple csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
r1=glob.glob("path/*.csv")
wr1 = csv.writer(open("path/merge.csv",'wb'),delimiter = ',')
for files in r1:
    rd=csv.reader(open(files,'r'), delimiter=',')
    for row in rd:
    print(row)
    wr1.writerow(row)
```

I am getting a type error 
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` not sure how to resolve this

Comment: I guess you need to open the file in `w` mode only not `wb` mode

Comment: Thanks curious mind for the reply...i got the below error when i changed it to w 
    TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What is the line with the _csv.writer error? By the way there is an indent error in the last 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` you can do it like this:

```
dfs = glob.glob('path/*.csv')

result = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df) for df in dfs], ignore_index=True)

result.to_csv('path/merge.csv', ignore_index=True)
```